# Visual Studio 2015 CreateWindowEx() uses different units for Debug/Release Windows API C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, visual-studio-debugging

I have made a simple base converter using C++ and Windows API in Visual Studio 2015. Everything went well, but when I was testing it in both Debug and Release modes, I noticed something weird.

Here's what my window looks like when testing in Debug:
[Debug Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBfsK.png)

But here's the same code, just compiled in Release Mode: [Release Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f79px.png)

The code to create the window is absolutely the same:

```
hWnd = CreateWindowEx(NULL, lpszWndClassName, lpszWndTitle, WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_MINIMIZEBOX, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 225, 350, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);`
```

But how does the same code, only one compiled in Debug and one in Release, produce different results?
In the documentation for `CreateWindow()`, the sixth parameter(`nWidth`) is described as:

> The width, in **device units**, of the window. For overlapped windows,
>   nWidth is either the window's width, in screen coordinates, or
>   CW_USEDEFAULT. If nWidth is CW_USEDEFAULT, the system selects a
>   default width and height for the window; the default width extends
>   from the initial x-coordinate to the right edge of the screen, and the
>   default height extends from the initial y-coordinate to the top of the
>   icon area. CW_USEDEFAULT is valid only for overlapped windows; if
>   CW_USEDEFAULT is specified for a pop-up or child window, nWidth and
>   nHeight are set to zero.

What are "device units" in this case? Are they pixels? And why are the units different for Debug/Release?

Comment: You shouldn't hard-code a window size. Start with the client size you need and use `AdjustWindowRectEx` to calculate the window size.

Comment: One config sets dpi awareness, the other does not?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I'm sorry, I am very new to windows programming. Can you explain what dpi awareness is? Also I'm not sure if it has anything to do with dpi awareness, since that the only two project config difference between the two are the platform toolset(one normal one windows xp), and Debug uses Multi-Threaded Debug DLL but Release uses Multi-Threaded.

Comment: I'm not nearly as familiar with this stuff as David, but it seems obvious to me that the Windows XP platform toolset option is likely to affect window drawing.  Change this setting so that Debug and Release are the same, and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks @HarryJohnston, that solved the problem! But I still have one more question: My controls are all created using `CreateWindow()` and `CreateWindowEx()`, but they are not affected by the Windows XP toolset. What causes this?

Comment: No idea, but I'd guess it has to do with window borders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @DavidHeffernan and @HarryJohnston's comments, the problem is now solved. The problem was because in the Debug config, the Platform Toolset was set to Visual Studio, but in Release it was Visual Studio - Windows XP. The XP config must have affected the drawing of the main window.